# JQUERY - fade out specifc div, wait, fade div back in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have this working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/B8Abd/

I would like to use jquerys fade out then fade in during the function. The code at the moment is this:

```
       function changetoYellow() {
//change the color of the div
       createGradientV([0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 0], 7, 200);
       }
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
       function changetoYellow() {
 //fade to black: 
       $("#fadeBandsV").fadeOut(1000);
//change the color of the div
       createGradientV([0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 0], 7, 200);
 //fade from black: 
       $("#fadeBandsV").fadeIn(1000);
       }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the issue? I don't see a question here.

Comment: @ThinkingSites he wants to fade to the next colour, see the JSFiddle and click the text (they aren't links so no hand-cursor)

Comment: The code I have above is guess that doesn't seem to work, I apologise I am but an enthusiastic beginner. Thank you.

Comment: @ThinkingSites: You're not looking hard enough. If you don't see a question..move on..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
function changetoYellow() {
    $("#fadeBandsV").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        createGradientV([0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 0], 7, 200);
        $("#fadeBandsV").fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/B8Abd/1/

Comment: Thank you! ...I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes apparently :)

Comment: +1 That's certainly what he asked for. Whether its what he really wanted though, I'm not sure (because it goes to the black background before it comes to the new colour).

Comment: Yep, and it looks really great :)

Comment: @Ozzy Yes it is what I wanted, but you're right, this is a bit of a work around for changing to another colour straight away - there doesn't seem to be a simple or straight forward way of doing this so I'm kind of cheating with this solution, but it does look good so I am happy. :)

Comment: @redditor the solution is to create a loop to change through the colours with a delay between each change `createGradientV([0-255,0-255,0-0], 7, 200)` But it you're right it still looks good as it is.